# Flask-SocketIO events in modules other than app.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

Flask SocketIO server implementation is not receiving client messages or event triggers when starting the Flask application (as per `socketio.run(app)`) using the flask command: `flask run` (on `http://127.0.0.1:5000`).

It is only outputting GET and POST polling:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 13:18:26] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nub1htW HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 13:18:26] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nub1i2I&sid=ELpMQjSfqpcXN731AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 13:18:26] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nub1i2J&sid=ELpMQjSfqpcXN731AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Project structure:

```
├── Flask Web App
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── common
│   │   ├── distributed_manager
│   │   │   ├── distributed_manager.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── local_settings.py
│   │   ├── models
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── js
│   │   │       ├── chat.js
│   │   │       └── responses.js
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── util.py
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── bot_views.py
│   │       ├── error_views.py
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── main_views.py
│   │       └── site_views.py
│   ├── flask_app.py
```

The app is initialised in `flask_app.py` by calling a function `create_app()` defined in `app/__init__.py`. This function returns a tuple containing the app object and socketio object, to be used to combine these two in the following way (in `flask_app.py`):

```
from app import create_app

app, socketio = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

I have managed to handle messages from client by placing the event handle functions in `flask_app.py` in the following way:

```
from app import create_app

app, socketio = create_app()


@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connection():
    print("Connected a client...")


@socketio.on("message")
def handle_message(msg):
    print("Client message: " + msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

But for separation of concern reasons and to decouple the app as much as possible I would like to place the server (EDIT: handle functions of the server) in the `distributed_manager.py`, because later I plan to pass the messages as requests in this module.

This is my server (`distributed_manager.py`):

```
from flask_socketio import send, emit
from flask_app import socketio


def ack_client():
    print("Message was received by the client.")

@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connection(message):
    print("connected: " + message)


@socketio.on("message")
def handle_message(message):
    print(f"Received message: {message}")
```

And client in `chat.js`:

```
var socket;
connectToSocket();
...
function connectToSocket(){
  socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  socket.on('connect', function() {
      socket.send('User has connected!');
  });
  // console.log("Connected to the socket.")
}
```

Comment: Are you using `flask run`? Try running the script instead. See the documentation, the flask run command is limited in what it can do when used with Socket.IO, best to run the script and let `socketio.run(app)` start the server.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it using `flask run`, but in `.flaskenv` file it is configured to FLASK_APP=flask_app. Solved this by moving the handler functions to an init function which is loaded before `socketio.run(app)` (see the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have connected my two brain cells and figured out that my `distributed_manager` module is executed after `socketio.run(app)` call and after creating the app so the `@socketio.on...` functions must be defined before it, specifically in my solution in `app/__init__.py`, which creates the app and socketio objects.

Comment: Better have two working brain cells than nothing